# Observable.Join example

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Can someone please provide an example of how to use Observable.Join with two different observable types?
The best explanation I've [found so far here](http://www.introtorx.com/uat/content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html#Join) says the left observable opens a window while the right one is for finding a match within this window which makes sense so for. But how is this `leftDurationSelector` and `rightDurationSelector` working? The example is just using `Publish().RefCount()` which I dont understand what it does. For me a duration selector sounds like a time span, e.g. a Buffer window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example that I think shows what happens nicely.

Let's start by generating two time-stamped observables `sourceA` & `sourceB` that each produce a value at a random interval of between `0` and `10.0` seconds:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
IObservable<int> source =
    Observable
        .Generate(0, x => true, x => x + 1, x => x,
            x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(rnd.NextDouble()* 10.0));

IObservable<Timestamped<string>> sourceA = source.Select(x => $"A{x}").Timestamp();
IObservable<Timestamped<string>> sourceB = source.Select(x => $"B{x}").Timestamp();
```

Let's have a nice way to output the values:

```
Func<Timestamped<string>, string> format =
    x => $"{x.Value} @ {x.Timestamp.LocalDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss.f")}";
```

So calling `format(x)` might return `"A1 @ 12:33:09.2"`, for example.

Now for the join:

```
IObservable<string> query =
    sourceA.Join(sourceB,
        a => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.0)),
        b => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.0)),
        (at, bt) => $"{format(at)}, {format(bt)}");
```

If I subscribe to this query I get a result like this:

```
A1 @ 12:33:09.2, B0 @ 12:33:12.4 
A3 @ 12:33:23.8, B1 @ 12:33:20.9 
A3 @ 12:33:23.8, B2 @ 12:33:25.6 
A3 @ 12:33:23.8, B3 @ 12:33:25.9 
A4 @ 12:33:30.6, B4 @ 12:33:33.0 
A5 @ 12:33:37.9, B5 @ 12:33:35.7 
A5 @ 12:33:37.9, B6 @ 12:33:40.3 
A5 @ 12:33:37.9, B7 @ 12:33:40.8 
A6 @ 12:33:43.3, B6 @ 12:33:40.3 
A6 @ 12:33:43.3, B7 @ 12:33:40.8 
A7 @ 12:33:44.5, B7 @ 12:33:40.8 
A7 @ 12:33:44.5, B8 @ 12:33:44.9 
A6 @ 12:33:43.3, B8 @ 12:33:44.9
```

I get the paired up results from `sourceA` & `sourceB` where either value is produced within `4.0` seconds of the other.

Now what if I only wanted a value from `sourceB` so long as it only was produced `4.0` seconds after a value from `sourceA`, but not the other way around?

```
IObservable<string> query =
    sourceA.Join(sourceB,
        a => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.0)),
        b => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.0)),
        (at, bt) => $"{format(at)}, {format(bt)}");
```

Gives me:

```
A0 @ 12:41:35.4, B1 @ 12:41:35.5 
A1 @ 12:41:42.7, B2 @ 12:41:43.2 
A3 @ 12:41:47.6, B3 @ 12:41:51.0 
A4 @ 12:41:49.8, B3 @ 12:41:51.0 
A7 @ 12:42:00.2, B4 @ 12:42:00.4 
A7 @ 12:42:00.2, B5 @ 12:42:02.5 
A7 @ 12:42:00.2, B6 @ 12:42:03.5 
A8 @ 12:42:04.8, B7 @ 12:42:06.4 
A9 @ 12:42:12.3, B8 @ 12:42:15.2 
A10 @ 12:42:17.2, B9 @ 12:42:19.7 
A11 @ 12:42:19.4, B9 @ 12:42:19.7
```

Note that all of the "B"'s occur after the "A"'s.

Or I can do it the other way around - where a value from `sourceA` is produce after `sourceB`, but within `4.0` seconds.

```
IObservable<string> query =
    sourceA.Join(sourceB,
        a => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.0)),
        b => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.0)),
        (at, bt) => $"{format(at)}, {format(bt)}");
```

This gives me:

```
A1 @ 12:43:23.8, B0 @ 12:43:21.4 
A1 @ 12:43:23.8, B1 @ 12:43:22.8 
A2 @ 12:43:27.9, B2 @ 12:43:27.3 
A3 @ 12:43:33.6, B3 @ 12:43:29.6 
A4 @ 12:43:36.2, B4 @ 12:43:35.3 
A4 @ 12:43:36.2, B5 @ 12:43:35.5 
A4 @ 12:43:36.2, B6 @ 12:43:35.9 
A5 @ 12:43:43.4, B9 @ 12:43:43.1 
A5 @ 12:43:43.4, B8 @ 12:43:40.6 
A6 @ 12:43:46.5, B10 @ 12:43:43.8 
A6 @ 12:43:46.5, B9 @ 12:43:43.1 
A8 @ 12:43:55.5, B12 @ 12:43:52.4 
A9 @ 12:44:03.8, B13 @ 12:44:01.2 
A12 @ 12:44:09.7, B14 @ 12:44:08.9 
A13 @ 12:44:12.8, B14 @ 12:44:08.9 
A14 @ 12:44:16.0, B15 @ 12:44:13.3
```

Note that all of the "A"'s occur after the "B"'s.

You can also use the query syntax:

```
var query =
    from a in sourceA
    join b in sourceB
        on Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.0))
        equals Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.0))
    select $"{format(a)}, {format(b)}";
```

Comment: Wow, very comprehensive example, thank you.
One more question: How to run this using TestScheduler?
For some reason the time stamp is always the same: https://gist.github.com/NKnusperer/96f4ee2834d2c2d65d46

Comment: @NKnusperer - Just add your scheduler to the `.Timestamped()` operator - `.Timestamp(scheduler);`.

Comment: Cool this works. But is there a better way to globally inject the TestScheduler for time relate operators then explicit passing it into every call?

Comment: @NKnusperer - No, I don't think so. Rx has been written explicitly to avoid global state like that.